# Realm migration android

Tags: android, database, realm

i'm making a migration for my realm database Android, this is the code:

```
if (oldVersion == 3) {

            schema.create("ContactLists")
                    .addField("id", String.class)
                    .addPrimaryKey("id")
                    .addField("name", String.class)
                    .addField("image", Byte.class);
            oldVersion++;
        }
```

The problem is that image field it'a a byte array, this is the model:

```
    @PrimaryKey
private String id;
private String name;
private byte[] image;
```

But i think that Byte.class is not correct for byte[] array, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
addField("image", byte[].class)
```